# MySQL Case with multiple conditions not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

This is really weird, I have this SQL query:

```
    select p.NAME, p.MEASURING_UNIT, p.EAN, p.ITEM_NR, IF(f.FORM_TYPE = 'InventoryList', log.QUANTITY_DIFF, fi.QUANTITY) AS VAL_QUANTITY, IF(IF(f.FORM_TYPE = 'InventoryList', log.QUANTITY_DIFF, fi.QUANTITY)>0,fi.GROSS_MONEY,0) as VAL_GROSS_MONEY, f.FORM_DATE, f.FORM_TYPE, f.DIRECTION, f.FORM_NR, pd.NAME as PARTNER_NAME, ad.CITY,
case f.FORM_TYPE 
    when 'Quotation' then 'Quot.'
    when 'Invoice' then 'Inv.'
    when 'Shipment' then 'Ship.'
    when 'Orders' then 'Ord.'
    when 'FacilityForm' then 'FacF.'
    when 'InventoryList' then 'InvL.'
    else 'Else'
    end as FORM_TYPE_CODE,
case f.DIRECTION
    when 1 AND f.FORM_TYPE <> 'InventoryList' then 'Sale'
    when 2 AND f.FORM_TYPE <> 'InventoryList' then 'Supply'
    when 3 AND f.FORM_TYPE <> 'InventoryList' then 'Moving'
    else 'Else'
    end as DIRECTION_CODE
from product p join form_item fi on p.id = fi.product_id 
join form f on fi.FORM_ID = f.ID 
join partner_data pd on pd.ID = f.PARTNER_DATA_ID 
join address_data ad on ad.ID = f.ADDRESS_DATA_ID 
join inventory_log log on log.FORM_ITEM_ID = fi.ID
where p.id =  8
AND fi.ID IN (SELECT l.FORM_ITEM_ID FROM inventory_log l, inventory_item i, product p 
WHERE l.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = i.ID
AND i.PRODUCT_ID = p.ID
AND p.ID = 8 )
and f.status > 1 
order by f.FORM_DATE
```

... and it looks like the second CASE function is not working like I expect. 
Right now if the FORM_TYPE is 'FacilityForm' AND the DIRECTION is 2 I would expect I get back in in DIRECTION_CODE 'Supply', but I gives me: 'Else'...

If I remove the second condition from it and remains this:

```
when 2 then 'Supply'
```

it's working, but I don't know why...

Can someone help me out here, what am I missing? Thank you.

BTW. this is the query result and the wrong value is in the last row:

```
NAME            MEASURING_UNIT  EAN         ITEM_NR     VAL_QUANTITY    VAL_GROSS_MONEY FORM_DATE   FORM_TYPE       DIRECTION   FORM_NR         PARTNER_NAME            CITY            FORM_TYPE_CODE  DIRECTION_CODE
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    20000           1371600         2018-05-16  Invoice         1           INV-00003/2018  Partner Ltd.            CityNameTest    Inv.            Sale
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    100000          1257300         2018-05-25  Invoice         1           INV-00006/2018  Partner Ltd.            CityNameTest    Inv.            Sale
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    50000           380365          2018-06-02  Invoice         1           INV-00008/2018  Good partner Limited    CityNameTest    Inv.            Sale
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    -33000          0               2018-06-27  InventoryList   1           INVL-00001/2018 New Partner             CityNameTest    InvL.           Else
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    -40000          0               2018-06-29  InventoryList   1           INVL-00002/2018 InventoryList           CityNameTest    InvL.           Else
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    -55000          0               2018-06-30  InventoryList   1           INVL-00003/2018 InventoryList                           InvL.           Else
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    -43000          0               2018-07-11  InventoryList   1           INVL-00004/2018 InventoryList                           InvL.           Else
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    30000           149850          2018-07-13  InventoryList   1           INVL-00014/2018 InventoryList                           InvL.           Else
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    21000           119880          2018-07-13  InventoryList   1           INVL-00012/2018 InventoryList                           InvL.           Else
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    0               0               2018-07-13  InventoryList   1           INVL-00011/2018 InventoryList                           InvL.           Else
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    0               0               2018-07-13  InventoryList   1           INVL-00010/2018 InventoryList                           InvL.           Else
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    0               0               2018-07-13  InventoryList   1           INVL-00009/2018 InventoryList                           InvL.           Else
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    -35000          0               2018-07-13  InventoryList   1           INVL-00008/2018 InventoryList                           InvL.           Else
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    -50000          0               2018-07-13  InventoryList   1           INVL-00007/2018 InventoryList                           InvL.           Else
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    50000           49950           2018-07-18  Invoice         1           INV-00009/2018  Good partner Limited    CityNameTest    Inv.            Sale
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    42000           41958           2018-08-17  Shipment        1           SHP-00002/2018  Good partner Limited    CityNameTest    Ship.           Sale
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    42000           41958           2018-08-17  Shipment        1           SHP-00002/2018  Good partner Limited    CityNameTest    Ship.           Sale
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    50000           49950           2018-09-04  Invoice         1           INV-00010/2018  Good partner Limited    CityNameTest    Inv.            Sale
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    100000          99900           2018-09-05  Invoice         1           INV-00011/2018  Good partner Limited    CityNameTest    Inv.            Sale
Test product    pc              EAN-PRD1    PROD-001    200000          199800          2018-09-27  FacilityForm    2           FAC-00002/2018  Company partner         CityNameTest    FacF.           Else
```

Comment: `case when f.DIRECTION = 1 AND f.FORM_TYPE ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using case against a column, you can't add extra conditions:

```
case ColumnA
when 1 then 'x'
when 2 then 'y'
else'z'
end
```

This works,because you're comparing the content of the column.

To use more than one condition, move the column inside the case statemnt:

```
case 
when columna = 1 and columnb = 2 then 'x'
when columna = 2 and columnb = 3 then 'y'
else 'z'
end
```